# Cannot reference both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have merged Xamarin.ios application (xib implementations) with visual studio application for IOS. I am getting above issue and cannot event make it work by removing either of them. Any other possiblities? How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference both, as they are different.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/

Monotouch.DLL is the old Xamarin iOS library starting from MonoTouch phase. It does **not** work with 64 bit iOS.

Xamarin.iOS.DLL is the latest Unified iOS library that works for both 32 and 64 bit.

Please stay at monotouch.DLL, or completely move to Xamarin.iOS.DLL.